# À quoi le mot "lourd" fait-il référence dans ce cas?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Bonjour,

Je suis tombé sur cette phrase : "Tous les autres comme moi c'était frit! Ils faisaient leurs trous dans les Artois... ou ailleurs!... **au 16e Lourd**!..."

Je vois bien qu'il s'agit du vocabulaire de la guerre, mais qu'est ce que ***Lourd*** veut dire dans ce cas ? est-ce un synonyme de "bataillon" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vu la forme « ordinal + adjectif », je pense que cela désigne une [unité militaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit%C3%A9_militaire) comme un bataillon, un régiment, etc. Les unités militaires d'un même type ont un numéro. L'adjectif *lourd* peut qualifier un type d'unité militaire, par exemple l'[infanterie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanterie) lourde ou l'[artillerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillerie) lourde. C'est donc une manière abrégée de dire quelque chose comme « 16<sup>e</sup> régiment d'artillerie lourde ». Cette tournure est courante, ce n'est pas une particularité de l'auteur.

Cette expression n'est pas spécifique au français. On dirait « *16th Heavy* » en anglais par exemple.

Au passage, l'expression « [faire son trou](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/429/faire-son-trou) » signifie réussir dans la vie, par exemple en ayant un bon travail. Mais ici, c'est une antiphrase. Ceux qui « faisaient leurs trous » dans l'[Artois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artois), ce sont des soldats [dans les tranchées](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerre_de_tranch%C3%A9es) de la première guerre mondiale. Il y a probablement un double jeu de mot, le trou pouvant aussi être une tombe pour ceux qui y meurent. S'il s'agit d'artillerie, « faisaient leurs trous » est peut-être à prendre au sens propre : ils tirent des obus avec des canons, et ces obus font des trous là où ils tombent. (Le fait que « trous » soit au pluriel suggère, mais n'impose pas, plusieurs trous par personne.)

Answer (score 1):

Il peut s'agir d'un régiment de chars.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_arm%C3%A9e_aux_%C3%A9poques_des_grandes_transf/0TVIAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22r%C3%A9giment+de+chars+lourds%22&dq=%22r%C3%A9giment+de+chars+lourds%22&printsec=frontcover)) Au mois de juillet de la même année , on a commencé à constituer le 1 Corps de chars , la 5 et la 6 divisions d'infanterie , le 4 régiment de chars lourds , le 23 régiment d'artillerie antiaérienne et la 1 brigade de barrage.

Il peut être aussi question d'un régiment ou d'un bataillon d'artillerie lourde. ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bataillon+d%27artillerie+lourde&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbataillon%20d%27%20artillerie%20lourde%3B%2Cc0)).

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_bataille_de_la_Moselle/rDAgAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22bataillon+d%27+artillerie+lourde%22&dq=%22bataillon+d%27+artillerie+lourde%22&printsec=frontcover)) Unité d'artillerie de soutien de la 5e division d'infanterie Etat - major du XXe corps d'artillerie 5e groupe d'artillerie de campagne 695e bataillon d'artillerie blindée de 105 mm obusiers 558e bataillon d'artillerie lourde de 155 mm auto ...